# 2 Particles systems (1 curve guide) Affecting both.

Tags: particles

I have 2 particle systems in the same scene, 1 particle system is following a curve guide (which is what I want), the 2nd particle system I just want to shoot out of the geometry as it normally would without following the curve.

From what I read online, the curve guide affects all particle systems in a scene. How do I get my 2nd particle system to NOT follow the curve guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn down the curve guide effect under "Field Weights" on individual particle systems:

[image]

Comment: You are the man! Thank you I even looked in that menu and somehow missed the curve guide option. I knew it had to be something easy. Thank you very much. I wll make sure to vote your answer as correct.

Comment: Cool and thank you for asking—I actually never used curve guides before, but I will now.  :)